# Why is $f_\epsilon(u) \in H_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I have to proof that $ u \in H_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ implies $|u| \in H_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ .
I can define $f_\epsilon(u)=\sqrt{\epsilon^2+u^2}-\epsilon$ .

it follows that $\nabla f_\epsilon(u)=\frac{u}{\sqrt{\epsilon^2+u^2}}\nabla u$.

Comment: For a fixed epsilon, the result is obvious, no?

Comment: not really , I have to show that $f\epsilon(u)$ and the derivative are bounded in the $L^2$ norm .

Comment: For the issue of $|u|$, have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639274/help-proving-a-map-between-sobolev-spaces-is-continuous?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can justify that $f_\epsilon(u)$ is weakly differentiable with that gradient, there should be no issue with proving they are in $L^2$. Note for example
$$ (f_\epsilon (x))^2 ≤  (f_\epsilon (x)+\epsilon)^2  = \epsilon^2 + x^2   $$
and for the second, note that $\frac{u}{\sqrt{\epsilon^2+u^2}}\in L^\infty$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93318/discussion-on-answer-by-calvin-khor-why-is-f-epsilonu-in-h-01-2-omega).