# Why is $f_\epsilon(u) \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

For $\epsilon>0$ let $f_\epsilon(u)=\sqrt{\epsilon^2+u^2}-\epsilon$

One calculates that $\nabla f_\epsilon(u)=\frac{u}{\sqrt{\epsilon^2+u^2}}\nabla u $  , for $\epsilon$ to 0 this term goes to $\nabla |u|$

and one finds$ f_\epsilon(u) \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$.

Comment: We need to know more about $\Omega$. Why is $f_{\epsilon}$ compactly supported?

Comment: $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ is a domain .

Comment: ok seems reasonable, but where is $f_{\epsilon}$ supported?

Comment: $f_\epsilon(u)$ should give an approximation of |u| with $u \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$

Comment: oh ok, so we have some $f_{\epsilon}(u)[x]$, that's to say we still evaluate on our space with variable $x$.

Comment: Yes , u depends on x .

Comment: What is wrong with the answer to this given in your other question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215634/why-is-f-epsilonu-in-h-01-2-omega)? It would help answers if we knew what it is you dont understand about that

Comment: @RhysSteele the answer I gave there seems to be exactly the same (in content) as the accepted answer here, with a similar discussion in the comments...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so it is clear that $f_{\epsilon, u}$ is compactly supported from the fact that $u$ is.

Now we do $\int_{\Omega}|f_{\epsilon, u}|^2(x)dx+\int_{\Omega}|\nabla f_{\epsilon, u}|^2(x)dx$. It is our goal to show these integrals converge.

$\int_{\Omega}|f_{\epsilon, u}|^2(x)dx = \int_{\Omega}u^2 - 2\epsilon \sqrt{\epsilon^2+u^2} \leq \int_{\Omega}u^2 < \infty$ by defn of $u \in W_0^{1,2}$

$\int_{\Omega}|\nabla f_{\epsilon, u}|^2(x)dx = \int_{\Omega}\frac{u^2}{{u^2+\epsilon^2}}||\nabla u||_2^2 dx \leq \int_{\Omega}||\nabla u||_2^2dx <\infty$ again by $u \in W_0^{1,2}$

Comment: The calculation shows that $f\epsilon(u) \in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$

Comment: Sure but $u \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$, and wherever $u = 0$ so is $f_{\epsilon}u$

Comment: The fact that u is compactly supported plus the calculation show that $f\epsilon(u) \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$?

Comment: yep that's right, the above space is just the compactly supported functions in $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$

Comment: thank you very much for your help .

Comment: I just noticed that $|f_{\epsilon,u}|^2(x)=2 \epsilon^2+u^2-2\epsilon \sqrt{\epsilon^2+u^2}$

Comment: it's fine as $2\epsilon^2 - 2\epsilon\sqrt{\epsilon^2+u^2} \leq 0$